# What type of power cable does the HomePod mini use?

Tags: hardware, power, homepod

Apple has released a new, smaller version of their speaker: [HomePod mini](https://www.apple.com/homepod-mini/).

[image: HomePod Mini]

One of my complaints with the original HomePod was its use of a [proprietary power cable](https://9to5mac.com/2018/02/10/remove-homepod-power-cable-video/) connector, which made it difficult to replace or shorten the cable. Most other Apple devices use industry-standard C7 "figure 8" power cables for mains wall power, or a USB-C or Lightning cable plus a power adapter.

What type of power cord does the HomePod mini use?

Comment: What's at the other end? Mains voltage, or…?

Comment: Have you had many occasions to remove the power cord from your HomePods? I’ve had  two for quite a while and not once have I ever needed to think about removing the cord. I guess I don’t mind a gentle coil when I have one pod 10 cm from my power.

Comment: @bmike I have a countertop Sonos with a perfectly sized [18" power cord](https://flexsonusa.com/products/us-0-35m-flexson-short-power-cable-for-sonos-play-1-black-single-model-flxp1035m1021us), easily swapped from the long one in the box. I'd consider wall/ceiling mounts for the HomePod but a long non-removable cord makes that much less appealing.

Comment: Aah. I didn’t consider mounting them where I couldn’t touch them on a ceiling. Cool idea. I hope the wiring works out for your dream project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HomePod mini was quickly opened up after release:

> - https://9to5mac.com/2020/11/18/homepod-mini-teardown-reveals-nearly-impossible-repairs-and-non-removable-power-cord/

Cord details:

- 6ft Power Cord.
- *Non-removable*, unlike the original HomePod, which could be yanked from the unit with a hard tug.
- USB-C on the wall-end.
- Ships with a 20W USB-C Power Adapter.

Answer (score 3):

The [Apple sales page](https://www.apple.com/homepod-mini/) does not contain a *single* photo of the power cord. It's as if they want you to think it doesn't have one...

I used [that page's "AR" feature](https://www.apple.com/105/media/us/homepod-mini/2020/d46a2713-1e83-4ac4-8c74-2a0abf9b8808/quick-look/homepod_mini_white_ios14.usdz) on my iPhone to view a virtual version of the HomePod mini on my table. I had to walk around to the other side of the table, then took a screenshot.

The AR HomePod mini appears to use the same round, proprietary, non-removable power cable as the original HomePod.

[image: AR HomePod Mini power cable]

Comment: That would imply shortening the cable length is a 5-minute job, if it's on mains. Lop off the moulded plug, shorten the cable, put a new plug on. Done.

Comment: @Tetsujin not really. What you say is true for the homepod. But the mini has an adapter so removing the mains plug to shorten or pass through a hole is not that useful. You need to do that to the cable between the mini and the adapter and we don't know what the connectors on that are

Comment: Ah, if it's DC, then it is going to depend on whether it's shielded or simple 2-core, though tbh, you could chop either & get away with a bit of 2A terminal bloc, 50p from any DIY store, keeping whatever plugs were on both ends.

Answer (score 2):

[The cable length is six feet](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/406666/5472) and it’s powered by the same small 20 W adapter as the iPad Pro ship with. Same size as the older 18 W adapter which will not work except to give an awesome safe red glow to the orb. So the mini has a cable fixed in the orb, that ends in a USB-C connector.

The adapter directly  plugs into the wall [20 W USB-C adapters](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210133)

[image: twenty watt usb-c power adapter]

The tech specs say 20 W power adapter and the published [efficiencies table lists 100 / 115 / 230 V input](https://www.apple.com/environment/pdf/products/homepod/HomePod_mini_PER_Oct2020.pdf).

- https://www.theverge.com/21561589/apple-homepod-mini-review

Two things to remember, [all cords are removable](https://twitter.com/MacRumors/status/1329115109050830848) and all machines generate smoke if you are sufficiently equipped and motivated.

[image: HomePod mini teardown]

Comment: This is most likely the case.  It's very rare nowadays for a product to have a power adapter **and** be hardwired to the product.  Whether it's a USB interface (USB-C, Micro, Lightning, etc.) or a simple barrel connector, they are (significantly) more often than not, *removable.*

Comment: I will order one sight unseen at the earliest opportunity @Allan - Almost bought my third full one but I’ll wait for these so I have one in the den / bedroom for my third device in the apartment.

Comment: Sounds like you've got a nice setup going there, would love to hear your thoughts on this second iteration of the HomePod.

Comment: The length of the attached cord would be useful, if you have it!

Comment: Soon! Hopefully very soon! @pkamb

Answer (score 1):

I feel the need to post this as an answer, even though it's really just a frame challenge.

*Late edit**
As it appears the Homepod will come with a power adaptor, the job just got even cheaper, if just as simple.
Clip the cable anywhere it will be out of sight & join with a bit of terminal block, 50p from any DIY store.

[image]

It's designed for mains voltages, but to comply with regs, would need to be encased in a supporting/insulating block for 110/240v. For low-voltage DC you can leave it in the open, or wrap in a bit of insulating tape if you're a bit <strike>*paranoid*</strike> wary.

You're going to need to do this to get the cable through any inconspicuous hole in your desk/wall/ceiling anyway. If the plug at one end is proprietary or even a standard small-form figure-8, it's going to be much harder to achieve, plus user-fit figure 8s are more bulky than their moulded counterparts.

Replacing a standard mains plug is little more than a 5-minute job for anyone with an elementary skill-set. It will almost certainly be a double-insulated structure, so you've only two wires to get right. Brown live, blue neutral.

Answer (score 0):

The cord is semi (hard tug) non removable from the side of the HomePod mini. On the other side, it is a USB-C plug. HomePod mini comes with this new 20W power-adapter that has female USB-C connector: https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MHJA3AM/A/20w-usb-c-power-adapter

Comment: Do you have a review unit? I can’t wait to see pictures of how this runs from the wall to the adapter to the unit itself.

Comment: RE: "The cord is semi (hard tug) non removable" -- Sounds like double-speak!

Comment: @user3439894 somewhat! _Can_ it be removed? Yes, pulling very hard. Is it encouraged? No, because there's a risk to break the plug or cord doing so, or make it too much wobbly when put back in place. It is possible, put it is not intended to.