# How long is the power cable on the HomePod Mini?

Tags: homepod

I'm thinking about ordering a HomePod Mini, and I want to put it in some places that might be just far enough away from a power outlet that the cord doesn't reach. How long is the power cable? 2 meters, [like the full HomePod](https://9to5mac.com/2018/01/26/homepod-2-meter-cable/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no official specs on the cable length just yet, but an early review indicates it's about 6 feet long. Also of note, it's permanently attached but terminates in USB-C.

https://www.theverge.com/21561589/apple-homepod-mini-review